# Google Cloud DNS zone file?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I would like to obtain a zone file for my Google Cloud DNS entries, but I don't see an obvious way to ask for it on the web app page. Is it possible to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to install the Google Cloud SDK https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads

Once you have that, it's a simple one liner in your terminal.

```
gcloud dns record-sets export yournewzonefile.txt --zone yourzonename --zone-file-format
```